# How do I fix this Eclipse error?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I recently tried running Eclipse on my Windows installation after several months (since I was working primarily on Ubuntu). Naturally, my java installation was outdated and Eclipse reported that it couldn't find a JDK to work with, so I proceeded to update the existing java installation. However, after the most recent version of Java was installed, the installer proceeded to uninstall the previous, outdated version of java (1.7), with my consent. Now, when I try to run Eclipse, this is the error message I get:

[image: Eclipse error snapshot]

It probably has something to do with setting of path variables or previous eclipse settings and the version of eclipse I'm using is from the Android ADT bundle (please do not ask me to switch to Android Studio; I have my reasons).

How do I fix this and get Eclipse up and running?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Eclipse?

Comment: Can't do that because the Android developer page doesn't offer an Eclipse ADT download anymore and I don't want to mess with downloading a fresh version of Eclipse and then get the ADT plugin, whose support has been terminated. I think it's something to do with my class path. How do I find the right path for java and add it to the my existing system path?

Comment: Have you searched this site before asking this? This is a common issue with many solution posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to re-install eclipse, if you read the log you will notice that `javaw` was told to use java 6, but it is obviously not the java version you are trying to launch with.

Simply change `1.6` to `1.x`  in `$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini`.

Comment: Actually, I was missing a JDK. Just installed the recent version and changed the config file as well so that it uses the right version. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error sounds you need to install JRE & JDK 1.6. 
I work on Mac OS. I have a similar case I have to install JRE & JDK 1.6 since the one coming with the original OS is newer than it needs

Comment: Yep! that and a minor edit in the .ini file. Damn, such a small thing...thanks though!